# How to save dataframe to pickle file using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, pickle

I have to save a dataframe to Pickle file, but it returns an error

```
df.saveAsPickleFile(path)
```

**AttributeError: 'Dataframe' object has no attribute 'saveAsPickleFile'**

Comment: @moghya I am looking for a solution of Pyspark not Pandas. Please check tags and title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`saveAsPickleFile` is a method of `RDD` and not of a data frame.

see this documentation:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=pickle

So you can just call:

```
df.rdd.saveAsPickleFile(filename)
```

To load it from file, run:

```
pickleRdd = sc.pickleFile(filename).collect()
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(pickleRdd)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if I understand it is necessary to convert my dataframe to RDD then save it to Pickle?

Comment: yes and no. yes, the rdd step is necessary, because it is an rdd method. No, it is not a conversion. rdd is the type that lies one abstraction layer below dataFrame. so there is no cost for 'converting'